# Choosing alternate implementations and forward declarations

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, clang++

I have a library which has a particular class used by downstream client code. This class derives from one set of base classes. e.g.,

```
A.h :-
namespace my_lib {
  class A : public BaseClass1 {
  };
}
```

Now, I want to provide an alternative implementation of class A that derives from another set of base classes and allow the client to choose which one to compile / link against. Thus, I want some way of releasing both implementations in the same shared/static library.

e.g.,

```
NewA.h :-
namespace my_lib {
  class newA : public BaseClass2 {
  };
}
```

I tried using typedefs but this causes problems with forward declarations. e.g.,

```
ClientA.h :-
namespace my_lib {
  #ifdef LEGACY_A
    typedef A ClientA;
  #else
    typedef NewA ClientA;
  #endif
}
```

Thus, the client would only use the class name my_lib::ClientA. However, this causes problems downstream if the client has forward declarations.

e.g.,

```
clientclass.h :-
namespace my_lib {
  class ClientA;
  class clientClass {
    clientClass(ClientA* a);
  };
}
```

This gives an error :-

```
clientclass.h: error: definition of type 'ClientA' conflicts with typedef of the same name
class ClientA;
      ^
ClientA.h: note: 'ClientA' declared here
typedef my_lib::newA ClientA;
```

On the other hand, if I use namespaces and the using directive, I again end up in trouble :-

```
A.h:-
namespace my_lib_legacy {
  class A : public BaseClass1 {
  };
}
newA.h :-
namespace my_lib_new {
  class A : public BaseClass2 {
  };
}
ClientA.h :-
namespace my_lib {
  #ifdef LEGACY_A
    using my_lib_legacy::A;
  #else
    using my_lib_new::A;
  #endif
}
clientclass.h :-
namespace my_lib {
  class A;
  class clientClass {
    clientClass(A* a);
  };
}
```

However, this throws ambiguity errors as follows :-

```
clientclass.h: error: reference to 'A' is ambiguous
  explicit clientClass(A* a)
                       ^
clientclass.h: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'my_lib::A'
class A;
      ^
ClientA.h: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'my_lib::A'
using my_lib_legacy::A;
```

Comment: I fear you end up in declaring an abstract InterfaceBaseClass collecting the common member functions of BaseClass1 and BaseClass2

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to avoid adding virtual function calls though... We get a great performance benefit from inlining...

Comment: What if you put both class definitions in the same header file, gave the classes the same name, and wrapped the entire definitions in the #ifdef conditional compilation directives?  Then you wouldn't have to change type names or header include statements when switching implementations.

Comment: I did think of that but I wouldn't be able to release the .o files for both implementations in the same library since the linker wouldn't know which version to link against given that they have the same name and namespace. I guess I could release two library versions so that is the fallback option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just tell your clients that they aren't allowed to forward declare your library components and use the typedef approach. This seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Since your library won't be changing all the time, and it already takes care of any dependency related forward declarations internally there should be no reason they need to rely on a specific internal implementation by forward declaring from your library.

If you wish you could also choose to provide a `<your_lib_name_fwd>` header that forward declares key components appropriately but I wouldn't consider that mandatory. This has precedent with for example the standard library's `<iosfwd>`

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll probably go with providing a seperate forward declarations header altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you could use

```
ClientA.h :-
#include "A.h"
#include "NewA.h"
namespace my_lib {
  #ifdef LEGACY_A
    typedef A ClientA;
  #else
    typedef NewA ClientA;
  #endif
}
clientclass.h :-
#include "ClientA.h"
namespace my_lib {
  // you already define ClientA with typedef
  class clientClass {
    clientClass(ClientA* a);
  };
}
```

or

```
ClientA.h :-
namespace my_lib {
  #ifdef LEGACY_A
    #define ClientA A
  #else
    #define ClientA newA
  #endif
}
clientclass.h :-
#include "A.h"
#include "NewA.h"
#include "ClientA.h"
namespace my_lib {
  class ClientA;
  class clientClass {
    clientClass(ClientA* a);
  };
}
```